# It's affecting with all li .subnav elements, how can i access only child element?

Tags: jquery

It's affecting with all li .subnav elements, how can i access only child element?

```
$("#left_content").on('click', '.left_navigation ul li', function () {
    $(".left_navigation ul li .sub_nav").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".left_navigation ul li > .sub_nav").slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need sub_navs under the li, then do this: `".left_navigation ul li > .sub_nav"`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and quickest would be to reference only the subitem within the thing that was clicked. `this` will refer to the item being clicked, so passing that as a second parameter to `$()` will only query elements nested within that `<li>`

```
$("#left_content").on('click', '.left_navigation ul li', function () {
    $('.sub_nav', this).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Calling `$(selector, this)` is the same as calling `$(this).find(selector)` fwiw, if people are unfamiliar with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup it's difficult to give an accurate answer, but it sounds like you just need to use `this` to toggle the relevant `.sub_nav`:

```
$(this).find('.sub_nav').slideToggle('slow');
```

`this` represents the DOM node which triggered the `click` event, and `.find('.sub_nav')` searches for descendents of that node with the class `sub_nav`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#left_content").on('click', '.left_navigation ul li', function () {
    $(this).children('.sub_nav').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method differs from [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.left_navigation ul li').click( function () {
    $(this).find(".sub_nav").slideToggle("slow");
});
```